# mysql- select records that exceeding certain time range

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a physician schedule page and Physician can configure his/her working time(start time and end time) from monday to friday.

By using visits page, Users can schedule their appointments only within physician scheduled time as per each day.

I am using visits table for user's appointments and physician_schedules table to configure physician working time.

**visits table entries**

```
id  visit_date  scheduled_intime    scheduled_outtime   physician_id
1   2012-04-23  09:15:00        09:30:00        1
2   2012-04-23  09:31:00        10:00:00        1
3   2012-04-24  10:00:00        10:15:00        1
4   2012-04-25  11:00:00        11:15:00        1
5   2012-04-26  15:15:00        15:30:00        1
6   2012-04-27  16:00:00        16:30:00        1
```

**physician_schedules table entries**

```
id  start_time  end_time    day_of_week physician_id
1   09:00:00    18:00:00    monday      1
2   10:00:00    18:00:00    tuesday     1
3   11:00:00    17:00:00    wednesday   1
4   15:00:00    18:00:00    thursday    1
5   16:00:00    20:00:00    friday      1
```

**Note** Each physician should have only one entry for each day(totally 5 entries).

**Question**
when physician changing his/her schedule time, I want to find out all the existing visits that exceeding physician schedule time on that particular day.

**Example**

1) I want to find visits ***id 4*** if physician change working time for wednesday as per

```
start_time: 12:00:00 
end_time: 17:00:00
```

2) I want to find visits ***id 4,5*** if physician change following working time

wednesday:

```
start_time: 12:00:00 
end_time: 17:00:00
```

thursday

```
start_time: 15:30:00
end_time: 18:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT visits.id FROM visits INNER JOIN physician_schedules
  ON visits.physician_id = physician_schedules.id
  WHERE
        UPPER(day_of_week) = UPPER(DAYNAME(visit_date))
    AND (scheduled_intime < start_time OR scheduled_outtime > end_time)
```

This will return all the ids for all of the badly scheduled visits for all of the physicians.  Add an extra WHERE to get them for just a particular physician.

Comment: Thanks man, you saved my time. One changes that need to add 'BINARY' keyword before comparing two string, otherwise mysql returns errors while executing query
**Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_cs,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='**